# How do I extract the GUI plotting part of this existing FOSS app (itrade)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have recently downloaded [itrade](http://itrade.sourceforge.net/), and so far I have been unable to get it to run (dependency on wxaddons amongst other things). Also, the project seems to have been disbanded since 2008.
Last but not the least, the project contains a lot of functionality which I just don't need.

All I require is the functionality to produce a graph similar to that shown on the Journalier tab in the image below; and to be honest, I don't even need all of the additional indicators shown in the image. I will be happy enough with the (1st) top chart and the (2nd) midle sub chart, without all the indicators.

I have had a look at the code, and since I am not familiar with wxPython etc, I am finding it difficult to locate the code that is responsible for producing the image below.

I'd be grateful if anyone with either wxPython or itrade experience could outline the steps needed (or explicitly state how) to extract only the section of the code that produces the image below. The objective being that I can read in data from a CSV file, and pass it to the new script, to display a GUI plot similar to the one shown below.

[image: itrade plot]

Comment: Why not just use [a plotting library](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html)?

Comment: Actually, I'm beginning to thing that my original idea was a dumb idea (borne out of frustration with itrade). I have just discovered boa constructor, and I am thinking of creating the GUI with that and ploting on the wxPython components using matplotlib. I think this will be the way to go, unless someone is able to prove otherwise to me in the next few days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to do this, this would be my approach:

1. Find the code that produces these tabs
2. Find the code that produces the visual graph for the Journalier tab
3. Find the code where the data is produced that is displayed in the graph
4. Find the code that passes the data to the graph and how it is processed before being displayed
5. Extract the necessary pieces of logic to produce and process the data
6. Use a plotting library to create the graph; it's easier to hook a plotting library into your application than to try and integrate this particular piece of visual code. Especially if you don't need most of the visual indicators.